# Android : rotate whole the layout

Tags: android, screen-orientation

[image]

How to rotate whole the layout to be like the screenshot with and without rotate the device ?

Answer (score 0):

In **Manifest** file, add the following attribute inside the corresponding `activity` tag:

```
<activity
     android:name=".YourActivity"
     android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
```

Hope this helps.